Can I connect two function generators in parallel?
I wish to connect the output of two functions generators together - Agilent 33220A and HP 33120A. When measuring with an oscilloscope, I see that even when idle, the outputs of those generators differ by 70~ mV DC. They both have a series resistance of 50 Ohm, so that would give a sink current of about 2 mA. I could not find a specification for this in the datasheet of the instruments.
The reason why I want to do this is to use a pulse generator to trigger both of them, one at the rising and the other at the falling edge, to output specific arbitrary waveforms with 10 ms in between.

Each waveform voltage will be at 50% due to the loading effect of the other signal generator.
